# Explicit specialization _of an inner-struct_ in non-namespace scope

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization, g++-4.7

I know there are a lot of posts about "*Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope*"; I already read most of them but (unless I didn't understand the answers well) they don't answer this specific question. As a matter of fact, I found a workaround in my program, but I'm interested to know the "real solution" to this problem if there is one.

### The problem

Please bear with me, it's difficult to put into words. I have a template class `A<typename T, unsigned n>`. I want to define a type-checker as a template inner struct `is_A<typename U>` which checks if `U` is some `A`. This struct inherits from `std::false_type` as is, and I specialize it to derive from `std::true_type` for template types `A<U,n>`.

Why do I want to do this? Because I want to define a template method `A::method<U>` that behaves differently when `U` is some `A` or otherwise.

### What worked

1. Putting the non-specialized definition of `is_a<U>` before the declaration of `A`. And put the specialized version afterwards with 2 template arguments instead of 1; *ie* `template <> template <typename T, unsigned n> struct is_A< A<T,n> > : std::true_type {};`. Why not, but I don't like so much adding a template argument, and exploding the definition of `is_A` is not so pretty either...
2. Removing `is_A` and using another type-checker for `method` which caracterizes precisely the type I expect (*ie*, whitelist approach instead of blacklist).

Is there another way than these workarounds which allows to write something similar to the following header?

### The code

Here is the smallest header I could write to reproduce the error:

```
#ifndef __EXAMPLE__
#define __EXAMPLE__

#include <type_traits>

namespace name
{


template <typename T, unsigned n>
class A
{
public:

    /**
     * Type checkers
     */
    template <typename U>
    struct is_A : public std::false_type {};

    template <> template <typename U>
    struct is_A< A<U,n> > : public std::true_type {};

    /**
     * Specialized method
     */

     // Version taking input of type A<U,n>
    template <typename U>
    void method( const A<U,n>& other ) {}

    // Version taking inputs of other types
    template <typename U,
    typename = typename std::enable_if< !is_A<U>::value >::type >
    void method( const U& x ) {}
};


}

#endif
```

Here is the error I get when I compile a cpp file including this header:

```
.h:21:12: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class name::A<T, n>'
.h:30:7: error: too many template-parameter-lists
.h:35:7: error: too many template-parameter-lists
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to work for me if you do as the compiler advises: Leave out the `template<>`:

```
template <typename U>
struct is_A< A<U,n> > : public std::true_type {};
```

Comment: You are right, it compiles for me too! :) I didn't know you could specialize a template without this `template<>`, can you?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn It's the normal syntax to specialize a template class, I actually don't see why you tried the additional `template<>`.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/ and http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html

Comment: @Sh3ljohn None of the examples in the links you posted uses both `template<>` and and addition `template<...>` for a partial specialization AFAICT. `template<>` is used for full specializations in the examples. There are (advanced) cases where you have two times `template<...>`, but yours is not one of those cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations :) I'm marking your answer as the solution then. Could I bother you for a link explaining these more advanced cases? I think this is the root of my problem here.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn You're welcome. You need the double-template syntax when you specialize a template function in a template class and you provide the definition outside of the class. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994775/c-specialization-of-template-function-inside-template-class) for an example.